# Why must new() constraint be specified last?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints

C# compiler requires new() constraint to be specified last.
According to MSDN:

> When used together with other
>   constraints, the new() constraint must
>   be specified last.

Why is there such restriction?

Comment: I'd guess at effective error reporting.  There are such a large number of possible errors, especially when there's a value type constraint.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the specification says so. It probably says so because it makes parsing the constraints a little easier. There is little value in allowing you to specify the constraints in any order and I can imagine some cost (including opportunity cost!) in making it possible.

Note, in fact, that the specification doesn't just say that you have to have the constructor constraint last, if you have it. It actually says that you have to have the constraints in the following order

1. Primary constraint.
2. Secondary constraints.
3. Constructor constraint.

Where a primary constraint is one that specifies the type parameter must be a reference type or a value type, secondary constraints are ones that specify a base class or interfaces, and the constructor constraint is the one under discussion here.

The relevant section of the specification is §10.1.5 and is definitely worthwhile reading.

Comment: @empi: When writing a grammar specification, I imagine guaranteeing uniqueness of one item while intermixing three categories of language-constructs is a bit of a PITA.  Saying it comes last is a simple and elegant solution.  You'll run across the same problems and same types of solutions when defining XML schemas.

Comment: Indeed, there is a cost to the proposed feature, with little benefit, and opportunity costs.  The opportunity costs are not just that time spent doing that feature is taken away from other worthy features; it is also that any time we allow variation in a syntax, that makes it more difficult to extend or modify that syntax in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Because on other constraints (class for example) you can specify a constructor while on other constraints you can't (Interfaces).

So if new() came first, then a constraint on an interface, you would get an error because you can't have the new() constraint on the interface.

Comment: But you can have a constraint that a type parameter *implements* an interface and has an empty constructor, so I don't think that argument applies here.

Comment: yes you are right, but you wouldn't be able to validate that unless the new() came after the class that implemented the interface (hence put the new() constraint last)

Comment: Keep in mind the constraints apply to the type parameter. So it's perfectly possible to have defined the grammar so that `where T : new(), IInterface` means that `T` is a type having a default constructor and implementing the interface `IInterface`, the language designers just chose not to the design the language in this way.

Comment: it definitely sounds like ease of validating the constraints may have been the real reason, I'm sure you could do it in any order but some predictability makes things somewhat easier.

Comment: @jonezy: Yes, that is my guess too (see my answer).

Comment: sorry Jason, I was kinda talking to/about your answer!

Answer (score 0):

YAQAPD: Yet Another Question About Parsing Direction

Every programming language has it's own rules. The direction of parsing is one of them. 
Let me explain in more detail (be patient).

Suppose that you write the following function in Pascal/Delphi:

```
function Sum2Numbers (n1, n2:integer) : integer;
begin
   result:=n1+n2;
end;
```

Now, the same function in C:

```
int function Sum2Numbers (int n1, int n2)
{
  return (n1+n2);
}
```

For the programmer's point of view, both function do the same thing (and really they do). 
However, behind the scenes, each compiler works on it's own way.

Pascal/Delphi and many other languages compile the code by parsing the text from LEFT TO RIGHT. 
So, when we call the function in Pascal or Delphi, the compiler put in the stack, first `n1` and second `n2`. 
The same function in C does it from RIGHT TO LEFT, i.e. the compilers put in the stack, first `n2` and second `n1`.

Both compilers read the parameters from stack in the ORDER they know, so all works fine.

All the "C-family" languages (C, C++, Managed C++, C++/CLI, C#, ...) they use the RIGHT TO LEFT order of parsing the code.

This is the reason why the `new()` constraint MUST be specified in the FAR RIGHT of the constraint list.
The compiler must know IN ADVANCE that will need to create instances of classes, BEFORE use them.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense IMO. Any source for your claims?